# Using view for select data from table of other user without grant option in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, sql-grant

I have a schema A with a view VIEW. (A.VIEW)
This view reads the data from a table TABLE in schema B (B.TABLE).

I have to allow an user (C user) to select data from view A.VIEW:

```
select * from A.VIEW;
```

When the user makes this query, receive the message "**ORA-01031 insufficient privileges**".

I have already given the grant:

```
GRANT select on B.TABLE to A (with user sys);
GRANT select on B.TABLE to C;
GRANT select on A.VIEW to C;
```

So keep giving the same error.

I saw on the net that the problem is solved by assigning the grant:

```
GRANT select on B.TABLE to A WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

**I don't want assign grant option: it's possible?**

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you query the view when logged in into schema A?

Comment: Yes. A can query the A.VIEW.
I have already given the grant:
GRANT SELECT ON B.TABLE TO A;